# ANDROID&PHP - How to display JSONArray from MySql using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

The code that I use to displaying value of table into JSONArray below

`send_data.php`

```js
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $query = "select id,ask from pertanyaan";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] =$r;
  }
echo json_encode(array_values($rows));

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and the JSONArray output is like [this](http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php)

`[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"pertanyaan ke 1","ask":"pertanyaan ke 1"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"pertanyaan ke 2","ask":"pertanyaan ke 2"},{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"pertanyaan ke 3","ask":"pertanyaan ke 3"},{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"pertanyaan ke 4","ask":"pertanyaan ke 4"},{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"pertanyaan ke 5","ask":"pertanyaan ke 5"}]`

but everytime i try that URL to display in android, i got an error that say

`Value <html><body<>script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

but when i create new API with the same output [here](http://www.mocky.io/v2/580c6b89100000f60754044a) into android studio, its work fine,

did i use wrong code to encode JSON from PHP?

Comment: How are you accessing the URL in Android? WebView in your app? Through a browser app?

Comment: @MikeM. ohh sorry sir if i already breaking the rules, i just suggested to ask a new question about php code,

@FredericKlein i try to displaying thats all value into `TextView` sir

Comment: http://zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php needs JavaScript to redirect to `http://www.`, try it with `http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php` in your request.

Comment: so i just need to add/enable JavaScript in my hosting folder sir?

Comment: For this simple request, you probably don't want to use a WebView or a headless browser with JavaScript support, just avoid the redirect by directly calling `http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php`

Comment: right sir, thank you

Comment: @Flix: was to hasty, the JavaScript does not only redirect. Give me a couple of minutes, will rewrite my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126442/discussion-between-frederic-klein-and-flix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

`HttpURLConnection` has no JavaScript support, but a needed cookie is generated using JavaScript.

Your call

```
String reqUrl = "http://zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php";
URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

fails, because the cookie `__test` is missing.

**Fix**

From a first glance at the JavaScript source the cookie seems to be constant for a given url, so it might be enough to set for a **constant cookie**:

```
String cookie = "__test=2bf7c15501c0ec57f8e41cb84871a69c";

URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

**Alternative:** Using a WebView we can grab the cookie, so this is the preferable approach, since it will not break, if the cookie changes and it is not much of a time delay:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getCookie();

    if(cookie!=null) {
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }
}

private void getCookie(){
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    WebView wv = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
    cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("zxccvvv.cuccfree.com");
}
```

and set it as in above example:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

**Output in logcat**

```
Response from url: [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"pertanyaan ke 1","ask":"pertanyaan ke 1"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"pertanyaan ke 2","ask":"pertanyaan ke 2"},{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"pertanyaan ke 3","ask":"pertanyaan ke 3"},{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"pertanyaan ke 4","ask":"pertanyaan ke 4"},{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"pertanyaan ke 5","ask":"pertanyaan ke 5"}]
```

Comment: sorry for slow response, i still dont know what the answer u mean above,
should i try the code into android studio??

Comment: Yes, I tested it on an Android device, booth approaches work, while I would prefer the WebView approach.

Comment: so I just need to enable javascript between hosting or android sir?

Comment: The host (`zxccvvv.cuccfree.com`) uses JavaScript to set a cookie, then forwards you to the data. The cookie seems to be static, so adding the cookie to your request enables you to request the data, bypassing the need for JavaScript. In case the approach breaks (the cookie might change) then the usage of a WebView to request the cookie can be used.

Comment: But when i searching, almost all of the tutorial using webview to set the cookie, do you have a simple coding just to enable the cookie? Or your answer above  is the right answer for me? Sorry for noob question, im so newbie about android studio

Comment: @Flix have you tried the WebView approach posted in my answer? You will see, that it doesn't cost you noticeable time, it's just a couple lines of code and a rather stable approach.